# How can I change nested table td border width using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, jquery-selectors

**HTML**

```
<hr />
<h1>Table-1</h1>
<hr />
<table class="tb1">
    <tr>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <table class="tb2">
                <tr>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <table class="tb2">
                <tr>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<hr />
<h1>Table-2</h1>
<hr />

<table class="tb1">
    <tr>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <table class="tb2">
                <tr>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
        <td>rw1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <table class="tb2">
                <tr>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                    <td>tbrw2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.tb1{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.tb1 tr td {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}

.tb2{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.tb2 tr td {
    border-bottom:1px solid #f00;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".tb1 tr:last-child td,.tb2 tr:last-child td").css("border","none");
```

There are a lot of table like below image and change some border with using jquery (I know little bit jquery) but there are some problems about border. Jquery change border of all td in last tr.I'm wrong about selectors. How can I fix this?

[image]

**JSfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/g5qLc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('table.tb2').find('tr td').css({'border-bottom':'1px solid red'});
    $('table.tb2').find('tr:last td').css({'border-bottom':'none'});
    $('table.tb2').closest('td').css({'border-bottom':'none'});
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/kTBum/3/

Comment: but the number of rows is changeable,I just did it as an example

Comment: @midstack the above code has no bound on number of rows in table. Only the last tr's border will be `none`.

Comment: The gray border at the bottom of `.tb1` should be hidden.

Comment: As the saying @Kolink  the grey border at the bottom of tb1 should be hidden

Comment: @midstack Test the above answer, now.

Comment: @midstack the css .tb1 tr td {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;} is actually overriding your jquery bottom-border coloring. And that's why probably it is not showing. In my case I change the border 2px in order for the changes to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Try `tr:last-child>td` to only affect cells directly within the last row.

Also note that you shouldn't use jQuery for that. Just add it to your CSS:

```
.tb1 tr:last-child>td,.tb2 tr:last-child>td {border:none}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5qLc/1/)

Comment: Is that important? IE7 is only used by people who have actively disabled Windows Update. If they make our life difficult, why should we care about them?

Comment: Well then, I guess you should keep the jQuery. But use the selector I have given you instead of your current one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(".tb2 tr:first-of-type").css("border-bottom","2px solid red");
```

I change also the css to:

```
.tb2 tr td {
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
}
```

From the original css:

```
.tb2 tr td {
border-bottom:1px solid #f00;
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
}
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g5qLc/2/)